# Text overflow: ellipsis not working for dynamic placeholder (on focus)

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an input with a dynamic placeholder. On focus I change the placeholder but some reason I lose my text-overflow: ellipsis property. But when blurred I regain it. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

I've prepared a stackblitz to play with:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jadz6i

Comment: This question is not on-topic as it does not contain a self-contained problem. A StackBlitz is welcome, but it must be an addendum to code in the question itself.

Comment: Were you able to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It's based on browser default functionalities. The purpose of the placeholder is to show whole information to user. But you can try it in Firefox, it works. Mine is 69.0.1 (64-bit) Firefox. Chrome doesn't support it.

Suggestions are

- make the input a little bigger
- Simplify the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
input:focus {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that did not work for me

Comment: I do not think text-overflow alone will work. It has to have the other properties along with text-overflow, like: white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden; and some width. for general reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/